# Microsoft azure owner isn't owner

Tags: azure-container-service

I am owner of a storage container on microsoft azure but I cannot access the containers and is asking me to talk to the owner which is me. Also I am not able to see any of the access keys which I am linked to any help is appreciated.

Here are the screenshots showing that I am using the owner account and am still getting the following message:
Access denied

You do not have access

Looks like you don't have access to this content. To get access, please contact the owner.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out our subscription was disabled.

I guess this is the default error screen on Azure if you cannot access something which is confusing if you are the listed owner of a service. Should probably inform the owner that their subscription is disabled opposed to telling them to talk to themselves.